# How do you search for the frequency with which a few specific words are used in Gmail chats with a specific person?

Tags: gmail, chat, google-talk

A friend asked me to make an info-graph in celebration of he and his wife having a baby due pretty soon. I have an idea for it - frequency of baby terms (baby, babies, kid, kids) by month in our Gmail chats over the past five years, overlaid with some baby related conversations during the same period in those chats which I can search for from memory, overlaid with a few of their big life events.

I am hoping there is an easier way to search the frequency with which the words mentioned above are used by month than to go through chat by chat (there are 898 of them).

Comment: Not a definite answer but more of an idea: you can download your gmail account data and use it in another software? This should overcome out Google's search limitations.